# Failed 12.04 upgrade, recovery mode unavailable with whiptail error

Tags: 12.04

Last night I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. The upgrade process had numerous errors, but I let it continue assuming that it would safer than interrupting it. Near the end, two conflicting messages appeared: "too many errors" and there was also a message telling me that the system was upgraded nonetheless. The only option I was presented at that point was to reboot, which I did, but the reboot just hanged. Then I tried to boot under "recovery mode" but the system gets into an infinite loop with the message

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 109: /lib/recovery-mode/options/whiptail: No such file.
```

I am at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got zero replies, but I fixed the problem, sadly by re installing from scratch from the Ubuntu-10.10-AMD6 DVD

This time I set up partitions manually to something like this:

/boot    primary     ext4 512MB

/        primary     ext4 150GB

swap                 ext4 100GB

/home   logical      ext4 remaining GBs

Immediately after the install the system warned me that 10.10 was no longer supported and asked me to *update* and then to *upgrade* to 11.04. After the updates I rebooted the system, then issued the command

sudo apt-get install nvidia-new

rebooted, and then upgraded to 11.04 . When the upgrade to 11.04 ended, I rebooted, went to system settings/Additional Drivers, where I saw that the nVidia accelarated graphics was activated “but not in use”.  I played to mae the dual-monitor system work,

Then I upgraded to 11.10, rebooted, did the updates, re installed tools I was using.

I am *NOT TOUCHING* 12.04 until I have evidence that the AMD FX-6100 MOBO works with the nVidia GeForce 550 Ti card works

So I am posting this response hoping to save for other people the countless hours I wasted.

Comment: You've set up swap to 100GB? That's too much. The recommended swap space is twice the amount of physical memory (RAM).